# Error while executing Pig Script using Spring xd

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming, spring-xd

I am trying to execute pig code snippet using Spring xd, but am not able to do so. I created a job using following command

```
job create --name Pig_job --definition "PigTest" --deploy
```

The PigTest job definition is defined as follows in the Spring xd modules/job directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"



xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">


<hdp:pig-runner id="pigRunner" run-at-startup="true">
   <hdp:script>
         student = LOAD '/user/KhiTest/Test123/student' AS     (Id:int,Name:chararray,Year:int);
         DUMP student;
   </hdp:script>
   </hdp:pig-runner>

</beans>
```

The job is getting created successfully but the deployment is getting failed. The log file is given below:

23:57:46,990 ERROR DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pigRunner': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:210)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deployAndStore(ModuleDeployer.java:88)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deployAndStore(ModuleDeployer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.deployModule(ContainerRegistrar.java:236)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.deployJobModule(ContainerRegistrar.java:697)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.onChildAdded(ContainerRegistrar.java:614)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.access$800(ContainerRegistrar.java:99)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar$DeploymentListener.childEvent(ContainerRegistrar.java:1020)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:100)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:819)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:399)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:365)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveReturnType(GenericTypeResolver.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.isExcludedFromDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 57 more
23:57:46,992 ERROR DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 server.ContainerRegistrar - Exception deploying module
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pigRunner': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:210)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deployAndStore(ModuleDeployer.java:88)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deployAndStore(ModuleDeployer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.deployModule(ContainerRegistrar.java:236)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.deployJobModule(ContainerRegistrar.java:697)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.onChildAdded(ContainerRegistrar.java:614)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.access$800(ContainerRegistrar.java:99)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar$DeploymentListener.childEvent(ContainerRegistrar.java:1020)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:100)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:819)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:399)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:365)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveReturnType(GenericTypeResolver.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.isExcludedFromDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 57 more
23:57:47,017  INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 server.ContainerRegistrar - Path cache event: path=/deployments/modules/allocated/cd96473f-2317-4b0a-877e-8abb4cc15c8f/Pig_Test.job.Pig_runner.1, type=CHILD_REMOVED
23:57:47,017  INFO Deployer server.JobDeploymentListener - Deployment status for job 'Pig_Test': DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pigRunner': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob not present
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:210)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deployAndStore(ModuleDeployer.java:88)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deployAndStore(ModuleDeployer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.deployModule(ContainerRegistrar.java:236)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.deployJobModule(ContainerRegistrar.java:697)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.onChildAdded(ContainerRegistrar.java:614)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.access$800(ContainerRegistrar.java:99)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar$DeploymentListener.childEvent(ContainerRegistrar.java:1020)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:100)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:819)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:399)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:365)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveReturnType(GenericTypeResolver.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.isExcludedFromDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 57 more
}
23:57:47,017  INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 server.ContainerRegistrar - Undeploying module [ModuleDescriptor@d8cfc80 moduleName = 'Pig_runner', moduleLabel = 'Pig_runner', group = 'Pig_Test', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = job, parameters = map[[empty]], children = list[[empty]]]

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecJob

Did you add pig to the module's /lib?

Comment: With Spring XD 1.1.0 we now include the Pig jar on the Hadoop classpath. Try using the latest release and also take a look at the example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-samples/tree/master/batch-pig . The best way to configure your job is to set it up as a batch job that uses the Pig tasklet in one of the steps.

Comment: I have the following jars in the /lib directory

batch-pig-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar  
spring-integration-jdbc-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar  
spring-xd-extension-jdbc-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar

Comment: So, in this case you don't have the pig jar but I don't think your code would work as a job anyway since you don't have a <batch:job> defined in your module config. The new XD release 1.1.0 includes the `pig-0.14.0-h2.jar` on the XD classpath. Could you upgrade to 1.1.0? If so, take a look at the Pig sample module - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-samples/tree/master/batch-pig